# SSD not detected in Windows and BIOS

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, ssd, bios

I have an [Intel 530](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DTPYT78) ssd on my [Asus Q550LF](http://www.asus.com/supportonly/Q550LF), and one more HDD, the one that came with laptop.  SSD is connected instead optical drive.

When I try to install windows on SSD partition, there is none! Neither in BIOS or Windows select option.( when I am selecting partition to install on).

But, when I run live Ubuntu from USB, there it is, NTFS formatted.
I have tried to do something with BIOS options in order to recognize it, my SATA mode selection is AHCI (only one I cannot change it).
And have tried with secure boot on/off with, then have tried to toggle everything on/off and restore BIOS to factory settings... But still nothing.

Comment: When you say 'one more HDD' do you mean, like, in a caddy that replaces your optical drive? If so, which one is in the primary drive bay?

Comment: @Chris , thanks for replay, I have updated my question. SDD replaces my optical drive.

Comment: Swap them. I'd bet that the Asus BIOS just won't recognize the SSD in the optical bay as a proper boot device. I have a couple Asus products, and I've noticed that the BIOS is typically buggy.

Comment: If the BIOS can't find it, how could Ubuntu see it?

Comment: I have no idea, it is not listed anywhere,  maybe BIOS sees it as optical drive, but Ubuntu knows some how that it is SSD.

Comment: Switching places of SSD and HDD resolve problem.